# How to use jquery-ui selectmenu extension methods(_renderItem, _renderMenu etc)

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-widget-factory, jquery-ui-selectmenu

The JQuery-UI selectmenu widget has some extension methods that can be used to customize rendering/styling of the dropdown select menu.
From the  [api docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#methods) , the following widget extension methods can be used to customize the menu:
 - _renderItem( ul, item )
 - _renderMenu( ul, items )

What i want to achieve is, overriding the above extension methods for just one instance of the selectmenu widget, and not at a global level.
The [widget factory docs](http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/extending-widgets/) does have example about extending a particular instance of a widget(example is at the bottom of this page), but haven't had any success in applying that to the selectmenu extension methods. 
Any insight for this issue is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, found the way to use the extension methods. Here is an example:

```
$('select-menu-id').selectmenu(options).data("ui-selectmenu")._renderItem = function(event, ui) {
  // override with custom logic for rendering each select option
}
```

Used the way autocomplete widget was customized by @Ben Olson in this article:
[Customize the jQuery UI AutoComplete Drop Down Select Menu](http://www.benknowscode.com/2014/03/customize-jquery-ui-autocomplete-menu.html)

Comment: The link now points to some some goofy sex and dating blog, I'm not sure if Ben got hacked or just had a midlife crisis.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use `.data('ui-selectmenu')` to gain access to the object (as suggested in the answer by @kashif_shamaz), the [API provides the `instance()` method](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#method-instance) to expose the object. The benefit is that this method is part of the API, and thus should be more stable and better-documented during potential future changes, compared to string-based access via the `data()` method.

Use as follows:

```
$('#select-menu-id').selectmenu('instance')._renderItem = function(event, ui) {
    // override with custom logic for rendering each select option
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For jQuery UI novices like me, an expansion of the answer from @tmpearce.  For a `<select>` input element:

```
<select id="foo">...</select>
```

The `selectmenu` widget must be created before you can call the instance method on it.  You can chain together the creation and access of the instance.

```
$( '#foo' ).selectmenu().selectmenu( 'instance' )._renderItem = function( ul, item )
{
  ...
};
```

Or, you can create the `selectmenu` widget, do other stuff, then access the instance.

```
$( '#foo' ).selectmenu();

...

$( '#foo' ).selectmenu( 'instance' )._renderItem = function( ul, item )
{
  ...
};
```

Or, my favorite, store the instance in a variable so that I do not have to specify the query selector more than once.

```
var menu = $( "#foo" ).selectmenu().selectmenu( 'instance' );

...

menu._renderItem = function( ul, item )
{
  ...
};
```

Vide:

- https://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#method-_renderItem
- https://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#method-instance