# Datepicker closing on loss of focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some JS that is executing on a datepicker that closes it. Whenever I select a date, it works. When I select the a month or a year from the selectmenu, an event is executing that is focusing off of the datepicker and closes it.

Any suggestions on how to track down this event?

**[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qc0go9a4)**

Relevant Code

```
$(function() {
  $(".isDatepicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showOn: "button",
    buttonText: "<i class='fa fa-calendar'></i>",
  });
});
```

Comment: If I run it with css it doesn't happen: http://jsbin.com/nofomih/edit?html,js,output

Comment: that jsbin isnt running the scripts from jquery-ui as provided in the original fiddle. @MoshFeu

Comment: `the scripts from jquery-ui as provided in the original fiddle` what do you mean? They both 1.12.1

Comment: You are correct. The issue is that the selectmenu function script that I added was removed. That is the section of code that is causing the problems in the datepicker widget. I need that for my custom selectmenus(jqueryui) @MoshFeu

Comment: That's the problem. The custom dropdown create div outside the widget, so when you click on that "dropdown" you actually focus out from the widget. You need to looking for a plugin which not create the "options container" outside the widget.

Comment: I am required to use jQuery UI. So i am trying to make code changes for that.

Comment: Is the plugin you use for the custom `select` is jquery-ui [selectmenu](https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/)?

Comment: Yes it is jquery-ui selectmenu

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130545/discussion-between-bldev-and-mosh-feu).

Comment: I think its too long time for me to look for the right answer, sorry, but here is a direction: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26773621/863110. Check if you can render the options container **inside** the colorpicker. In this way the `blur` event will not fire just like with regular select.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to the question of how to track it down, Firebug (development tool for Firefox) lets you set a breakpoint on removal or editing of an HTML element. I believe it's in the menu when you click on the element in the DOM tree. And I imagine other browsers have something equivalent.

Comment: Sorry but it's not an answer, it should be a comment.

Comment: It's a partial answer, since OP asked "Any suggestions on how to track down this event?".

Answer (score 0):

You have conflicting scripts I believe.

Remove the code below and it works as designed.

```
  $("button.ui-datepicker-trigger").click(function() {
    $("select").selectmenu();
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6m42tw6d/

Comment: I need this for the custom selectMenu element of Jquery UI. I have added cleaned up some js in the new https://jsfiddle.net/k0LyL4Ld/ @bassxyzero

Comment: Something is executing after this selectmenu has been executed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `selectmenu();` initialization on all the `select` elements. Here is the **[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/qc0go9a4/4/)** where I've commented the `selectmenu()` initialization.

Solution would be, you need to target specific `select` elements or filter out `select` element from `datepicker`. The behavior is mixing up within.

Comment: the selectmenu is needed to be applied to all select menus. The problem is when the jQuery UI selectmenu is executed, it closes the widget on focus or click @guruprasad-rao

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing the menu more than once. If you need to refresh it, you can use "refresh":

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on('show.bs.modal', function() {
    $("select").selectmenu( "refresh" );
  });
  $("button.ui-datepicker-trigger").click(function(e) {
     $("select").selectmenu( "refresh" );
  });

  $("select").selectmenu();
  $("select").change(function() {
    alert("no");
  });
});
```

Comment: That doesnt seem work. I want to apply all of the select menus with the selectmenu script. This doesnt work when things are loaded after the fact, such as a modal or this datepicker widget.